# Having issue displaying the information of a form in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-activity, registerforactivityresult

I have written the following code in Android Studio to print the information of a register form:

```
package com.example.session8_project1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

public class RegisterButtonActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn;

EditText Name, LastName, Email, Password;

RadioGroup genderRadioGroup;

RadioButton genderRadioButton;

CheckBox chk;
int genderId;

Boolean Conditions;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_button);

    btn = findViewById(R.id.reg_button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            chk = findViewById(R.id.CheckBoxConditions);

            // Find Ids
            Name = findViewById(R.id.NameText);
            LastName = findViewById(R.id.LastNameText);
            Email = findViewById(R.id.EmailText);
            Password = findViewById(R.id.PasswordText);

            // Convert to String
            String name = Name.getText().toString();
            String lastname = LastName.getText().toString();
            String email = Email.getText().toString();
            String password = Password.getText().toString();

            genderRadioGroup = findViewById(R.id.RadGrp);

            genderId = genderRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            genderRadioButton = findViewById(genderId);

            String gender = genderRadioButton.getText().toString();

            // Check whether the Checkboxes are selected or not.
//                Conditions = chk.isChecked();
              Conditions = chk.isSelected();

            Intent in = new Intent(RegisterButtonActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
            in.putExtra("name ", name);
            in.putExtra("lastname ", lastname);
            in.putExtra("email ", email);
            in.putExtra("password ", password);
            in.putExtra("gender ", gender);
            in.putExtra("Conditions ", Conditions);

            startActivity(in);

        }
    });
}
```

}

And the activity to which this code is applying is as follows:
package com.example.session8_project1;

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ResultActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView result;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    result = findViewById(R.id.ResultText);

    if (extras != null){

        result.setText(extras.getString("name") + "\n" +
                extras.getString("lastname" )+ "\n" +
                extras.getString("email") + "\n" +
                extras.getString("password") + "\n" +
                extras.getString("gender") + "\n" +
                extras.getBoolean("Conditions"));
    }
}
```

}

When I fill the information of the form, it will give me the `null` result. I do not know why? is there something wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `putExtra`, you are using:

```
in.putExtra("name ", name);
```

Note that the key you are using is `"name "` - with a space at the end.

When you are retrieving that extra, you are using

```
extras.getString("name")
```

With the key `"name"` - without a space at the end.

Those need to match, so you should consistently use `"name"` in both places.

Comment: Thank You so much. I figured it out. So the key names must be exactly the same as the result activity in the "extras" object. Right?

Comment: Yep, if you're retrieving something via the key `"name"`, then you have to put it into extras using that same key.